# Using a custom UITableViewController class in Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, xcode-storyboard

In my storyboard, I have created a new UITableViewController object for which I would like to specify some custom code. I created a new controller with the following header:

```
@interface CustomController : UITableViewController
```

When I select the UITableViewController in the Storyboard view and navigate to the Identity Inspector, I can see my `CustomController` in the Custom Class drop-down. However, when I select it, I hear an error sound, which is referred to as "Morse" in the system preferences.

When I deselect the UITableViewController and re-select it, it has cleared my `CustomController` selection and replaced it with `UITableViewController`. I do not understand why XCode does not accept this, as from my understanding, this is all that is required to add your own code to a UITableViewController. I am not sure if I have encountered an XCode bug or if I have configured my class incorrectly.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the CustomController or adding another "CustomController2" and starting fresh with a newly inherited UIViewController subclass?

Comment: Good call. It turns out that if you convert a UIViewController to a UITableViewController, that's still not enough to use it as a UITableViewController in a storyboard. So, another bug in XCode has been discovered. If you'd care to write that as an answer to this question, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use a UIViewController as a UITableViewController, but you have to do some work. If you "convert" a UIViewController to a UITableViewController, you'll need to implement the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource protocols. You may also need to provide an outlet for a UITableView. You'll also need to handle keyboard events. Basically a bunch of effort for not much return.
Probably best in your case to start fresh with a new UIViewController class inheritted from UITableViewController.